# Migrating Trac 0.12 from Debian wheezy to Trac 1.0.2 on jessie including all plugins

Tags: trac

I try to migrate a trac installation from a debian wheezy server to another debian jessie.

If I copy all files to the new server I get the message, that I have to upgrade with `trac-admin /var/trac/blimus upgrade`, which seems to work, but it seems not to update all plugins.

for example I had a plugin installed in the old trac, that lets you login on a webpage instead of the htaccess popup.

On the new server I now get the error

```
Error: Not Found
No handler matched request to /login
```

How do I get the web-login back?

Is there a way to analyze the old trac folder, which plugins were installed, so I can install the missing ones in the new installation?

I checked the new trac.ini file and added the missing options, [this is my trac.ini](https://paste.toppoint.de/?dbc4a1611897081c#1fCjymRGb5C5jVbjZMdhnhWUc7ymQ2SzWri6f5gw1dE=)

These are my versions:

```
# trac-admin --version          
Warning: Detected setuptools version 5.5.1.
Welcome to trac-admin 1.0.2
```

Comment: The `Warning: Detected setuptools version 5.5.1.` is due to using setuptools in the range 5.4 to 5.6, which had performance problems. There is a [workaround](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#MandatoryDependencies), or just use a version outside that range. You can just use the latest setuptools, which is currently 42.

Comment: Trac 1.0.2 is rather old. [Debian Buster](https://packages.debian.org/buster/trac) and [Debian Stretch](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/trac) have a 1.2.x version of Trac.

Comment: But unfortunately I have to install it on a Debian Jessie server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This instruction will work on Debian jessie (Trac 1.0.2), as well as Ubuntu 14.04 trusty (Trac 1.0.1)

## Prerequisites

#### On your old Debian wheezy server:

```
# cd ~/
# tar -cvzf trac-example.tgz /var/trac/example
# cp /var/trac/example/conf/trac.ini trac.ini-example
# update your trac.ini-example to match new settings
```

## Installation on the new server

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

####################### config ##############################
INSTALLPATH=/var/trac/example
DEPLOYPATH=/var/www/trac-example
# where you store your tgz backup and the new trac.ini file
BACKUP_PATH=~/
#############################################################

# install packages without user interaction:
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

apt-get -y install unzip apache2 trac trac-accountmanager trac-xmlrpc libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-python-doc libapache2-mod-wsgi
a2dismod python
a2enmod rewrite

# add trac user for apache WSGIDaemonProcess:
adduser --shell /bin/sh --no-create-home --disabled-password trac
mkdir -p /home/trac/.keep-for-mod_wsgi

mkdir -p /var/trac
```

### # extract the tar-gz file of the trac installation from the old server

```
tar -C /var/trac/ -xvzf $BACKUP_PATH/trac-example.tgz 

 # copy your new config here:
cp $INSTALLPATH/conf/trac.ini $INSTALLPATH/conf/trac.ini-backup
cp $BACKUP_PATH/trac.ini-example $INSTALLPATH/conf/trac.ini
```

### # remove old plugins and eggs

```
rm -rf $INSTALLPATH/plugins/nevernotifyupdaterplugin-0.0.* $INSTALLPATH/eggs/*
```

### # update Trac

```
cd $INSTALLPATH/
trac-admin $INSTALLPATH upgrade
trac-admin $INSTALLPATH wiki upgrade
trac-admin $INSTALLPATH deploy $DEPLOYPATH/
chmod ugo+x $DEPLOYPATH/cgi-bin/ $DEPLOYPATH/htdocs/

# downgrade genshi from 7.3 to 6.0 due to error when adding an attachment:
easy_install -U Genshi==0.6
# upgrade setuptools
easy_install -U setuptools==1.4.2
```

### # install neverNotifier Plugin

# (This is still needed on trac 1.0.x, on 1.2 ist is obsolete)

```
cd /tmp
wget "https://trac-hacks.org/browser/nevernotifyupdaterplugin/1.0?r│
ev=17630&format=zip"
unzip 1.0\?r*
cd 1.0/
python setup.py bdist_egg
cp dist/nevernotifyupdaterplugin-1.0-py2.7.egg $INSTALLPATH/plugins/
```

### # setup hosts file

```
VHOST=$(cat <<EOF
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Alias /trac/chrome/common $DEPLOYPATH/htdocs/site/common
  Alias /trac/chrome/site $DEPLOYPATH/htdocs/site
  <Directory "$DEPLOYPATH/htdocs">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Location "/trac">
    SetEnv TRAC_ENV "$INSTALLPATH"
    SetEnv PYTHON_EGG_CACHE "$INSTALLPATH/.python-eggs"
    SetEnv TRAC_ENV_INDEX_TEMPLATE $INSTALLPATH/templates
  </Location>
  ##trac mit mod_wsgi
  WSGIDaemonProcess trac user=trac group=trac threads=25
  WSGIScriptAlias /trac $DEPLOYPATH/cgi-bin/trac.wsgi
  <Directory $DEPLOYPATH/apache>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory $DEPLOYPATH/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory $DEPLOYPATH/htdocs/common>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Directory $DEPLOYPATH/htdocs/site>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
EOF
)
```

### # apache config

```
echo "${VHOST}" > /etc/apache2/sites-available/trac-example.conf
a2ensite trac-example
```

On a fresh installed systen, disable the default apache config

```
rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

then restart apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: The recursion problem exists because `$INSTALLPATH/htdocs` is actually the environment `htdocs` dir, used for site customizations, and should not be used as the target for extraction of static resources, which is the result you have in your environment. This is a common problem due to the way the docs were written in older versions of Trac.

Comment: 3. Give [TracUpgrade](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade) a read through.

Comment: 5. Create a `virtualenv` to avoid polluting the global `site-packages`, which `apt` will install packages to, with manually (`easy_install`/`pip`) installed packages.

Comment: 6. Use `pip` rather than `easy_install`. It's the modern package manager for Python and includes an uninstall command. It will install packages in the wheel format, which avoids potential egg-extraction problems. I'd also recommend upgrading `setuptools` to the latest, and I think the error adding attachments was resolved in a Genshi 0.7.x version.

Comment: 8. You don't need ` libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-python-doc` since your Apache configuration uses only `libapache2-mod-wsgi`.

Comment: 9. [trac-users mailing list](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/MailingList#Trac-users) is another good resources if you have more questions, though you may just get a response from me there as well ;)

Comment: I would definitely run the `deploy` command, as you could be using old versions of the static resources if you were previously running an older version of Trac. If you encounter a recursion error then you will need to relocate the assets to a `www` directory. I would also suggest updating your Apache config to use `Require ...`, but that might be little less important.

Comment: thaks, @RjOllos, I used `deploy` now (you can revise some of your comments now)

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin were installed in the Environment `plugins` directory as `eggs`, they will be carried over to your new server when you copied the the environment. However, you almost certainly need to upgrade to newer versions, so I suggest deleting the eggs from the Environment `plugins` directory. The plugins might also have been installed in Python's `site-packages`. Or they could have been installed using Debian's package manager, I'm not sure if plugins are available there, you might want to search using `apt`. See [Trac Plugin documentation](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPlugins#Plugindiscovery).

Which version of Trac are you running now? I assume it's 1.2.3.

You `trac.ini` shows that you have 3 plugins installed, and you no longer need one of them in Trac 1.2 ([NeverNotifyUpdaterPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/NeverNotifyUpdaterPlugin)). You should install these two:
 * [AccountManagerPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin)
 * [XmlRpcPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin)

I don't know if Debian packages those for distribution. If not, you can [install them with pip](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPlugins#Usingpip).

Comment: Those plugins exist, I installed with `apt install trac trac-accountmanager trac-xmlrpc` but still the same problem: `No handler matched request to /login`

Comment: I had those eggs: `Genshi-0.5.1-py2.5-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp` and `TracAccountManager-0.2.1dev_r4679-py2.5.egg-tmp` I deleted those folders, do I have to rebuild the eggs somehow?

Comment: `apache2ctl graceful` was enough to reload trac

Comment: What happens, if you don't delete the tmp files in the egg folder?

Comment: `service apache2 reload` is another good way. Looks like the `.egg-tmp` files are related to the egg extraction (`PYTHON_EGG_CACHE`), so they should be harmless, whether you delete them or not.

Comment: In fact, those `.egg-tmp` files should only be found under `$INSTALLPATH/.python-eggs`, and if they are found in another location such as `$INSTALLPATH/plugins`, that may be due to a previous configuration where the `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` pointed to `$INSTALLPATH/plugins`.

Comment: I see you are running 1.0.2, so you'll need to install [NeverNotifyUpdater](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/NeverNotifyUpdaterPlugin) if you want that functionality.